# Remover div se input estiver vazio

Tags: jquery, input, div

Gostaria de excluir essa `div` se o `input` receber um valor vazio.

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-2 usuario">
    <label>Usuário:</label>
      <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" 
             id="usuario" value="<?php echo $rows['usuario']; ?>"
      >
</div>
```

Tentei usar o `JQuery`, porém acaba excluindo mesmo se o campo tiver preenchido.

```html
if ('input[value=""]') {
    $('.usuario').remove();
}
```

Comment: faltou dizer em qual momento você deseja fazer isso, é um evento `onclick`, `onblur` etc ... em qual momento você deseja fazer isso?

Comment: Quando a página é carregada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vou te apresentar uma outra forma de fazer isso, um pouco mais clara e que talvez possa te trazer mais conhecimento sobre a lógica.

```
var inputValue = $('#usuario').val()

// so ira entrar no IF se o valor for nulo/vazio etc.
if (!inputValue) {
  $('.usuario').remove()
}
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Exatamente o que eu procurava. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade, o a sua condição não está sendo comparada corretamente.

Para fazer isso da forma correta basta utilizar este script:

```
// Primeiro você precisa capturar o valor
var inputUsuario = $('#usuario').val();

// Agora é feita a condição (nulo/vazio)
if(!inputUsuario){
    $('.usuario').fadeOut();
}else{
    // Fiz este else pois caso você precise verificar em tempo real se há usuário, 
    // terá um efeito de fade in.
    $('.usuario').fadeIn();
}
```

Antes de colocar isso no seu código, tente entender a lógica por trás. Qualquer coisa, basta comentar ;)

Espero ter ajudado.